# Flashvars to stop flash movie reloading on page reload

Tags: flash, refresh, reload, flashvars, banner

I have a flash banner on every page in my site. I want it to continue playing rather than reloading when users change pages. Ive read that this can be achieved using flashvars, however, its been quite some time since I did any actionscripting. I've tried looking up tutorials to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

**UPDATED**

Thanks for your comments. I have this on frame 1 of my fla file now:

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("displayCookie");
if(mySharedObject.data.displayed == true){
gotoAndPlay(currentFrame); 
    trace("cookie found");
}else{
    trace("cookie not found, setting it now");
    //do whatever if NOT already been played
    mySharedObject.data.displayed = true;
    mySharedObject.flush();
}
```

But I don't know how to give the currentFrame the value it had at the time the page was refreshed. How do I put that in there?

Sorry for my noobness

Comment: When you say continue playing, do you want to pass a "currentframe" from one page to the next...then have the banner start at that frame?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want

Comment: You don't want `flashvars` you want [SharedObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html), which is essentially flash cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your SharedObject code, you could do something like this:

On frame 1:

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("displayCookie");

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkLoadedFrames);

function checkLoadedFrames(e:Event):void {
   if(this.framesLoaded == this.totalFrames) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkLoadedFrames);
        checkSharedObject();
   }
}

function checkSharedObject():void {
    if(mySharedObject.data.currentFrame){
       gotoAndPlay(mySharedObject.data.currentFrame); 
    }
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, saveCurrentFrame);
}

function saveCurrentFrame(e:Event):void {
   mySharedObject.data.currentFrame = this.currentFrame;
}
```

Comment: I thought this had worked, but it always seems to reload the same 2 frames on a page refresh. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, you would most likely need to do a bit more than the short example code above in a full solution. First and foremost, you would need to make sure that all frames are loaded before you call gotoAndPlay. I'll update the answer somewhat (but it is still up to you to make the production code).

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably be a little more complicated than just using FlashVars. You'll also need to use a little ExternalInterface to get the current frame of the banner once the user navigates to the next page. (Note: I'm using jQuery and swfobject)

First, the javascript would be something like:

```
var flashObj;

$(document).ready(function() {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
          flashObj = window["flash"];
     } else {
          flashObj = document["flash"];
     }
});

function embedPlayer() {
     var flashvars = {};
     if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("frame")) {
          flashvars.bannerframe = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("frame");
     } else {
          flashvars.bannerframe = 1;
     }
     var params = {};
     var attributes = {};
     swfobject.embedSWF("swf/Main.swf", "flash", "800", "600", "10.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
}

function getBannerFrame() {
     return flashObj.checkCurrentFrame();
}
```

Then, in your FLA on frame 1, you would have:

```
var frame:Number = Number(root.loaderInfo.parameters.bannerframe);
if (!isNaN(frame)) {
     gotoAndPlay(frame);
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("checkCurrentFrame", checkCurrentFrame);

function checkCurrentFrame():int {
     return this.currentFrame;
}
```

Now, any time you navigate to another page, you just tack on the current frame to the query string using `checkCurrentFrame();`

Comment: :| you've lost me. If its really that complicated I think I'm gonna have to resolve this some other way. Understanding what you've just put is gonna take a fair bit of learning first, time for which I just don't have.